# Salesforce BULK upload always fails

Tags: salesforce, bulk, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I'm uploading a simple CSV file using the following steps

1- Creating a Job

```
POST {{instance_api_name}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest/
{
    "columnDelimiter" : "COMMA",
    "object" : "portfolio__c",
    "externalIdFieldName" : "portfolio_external_id__c",
    "contentType" : "CSV",
    "operation" : "upsert",
    "lineEnding" : "CRLF"
}
```

2- Add CSV file to the Job

```
{{instance_api_name}}/services/data/v43.0/jobs/ingest/{{job_id}}/batches
```

attached with the following simple CSV file

```
Name,allow_trigger__c,portfolio_external_id__c
Airline,FALSE,blabla
```

3- Close the created Job

```
{{instance_api_name}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest/{{job_id}}
```

On Salesforce, the Job id appears with Failed status. The failed reason is the following

```
null:InvalidBatch : InvalidBatch : Field name not found : ----------------------------355072916529311982669462. Batch will not be retried.
```

Don't know why the field name is -------------- following with long number.

based on my research the CSV file should be saved *Comma Separated Values (.csv)*, I did that and no progress.

Any solution for that? or any clear reason why the JOB is failing?

Comment: Have you looked at the data file to see if that text appears? Depending on how you generated the file it's possible you have a whole string of ----- in there meant for separating sections visually.

Comment: @acrosman, I see, but my CSV file is looks like I mentioned in the above description.